# mainWindow.loadURL("https://localhost:3000/") show white screen on Electron app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, http, localhost, electron

I am trying to make an with React and Electron. When I use http, it's working perfectly.

```
app.on('ready', () => {
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    titleBarStyle: "hidden",
    width: 1000,
    height: 700,
  });
  mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();
  mainWindow.loadURL("http://localhost:3000");});
```

But I need to use the protocol https for my app, so I am writing to run the react script : `HTTPS=true npm start`. It's running on Chrome with the link https://localhost:3000/. But when I change the mainWindow.loadURL to `mainWindow.loadURL("https://localhost:3000")`
It show a white screen without error in the console.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The issue is because of the certificate error.

Try adding the following lines inside your main.js file.

```
app.on('certificate-error', function(event, webContents, url, error, 
  certificate, callback) {
      event.preventDefault();
      callback(true);
});
```

If you want your application to run on `https`, the ideal solution would be to use the proper certificate.

Hope you find this helpful.